# Xcode 9 stucked on waiting to Attach _name of app on simulator

Tags: xcode, simulator

I cannot run my app on the simulator, 
[image: this is my run scheme what should I do?]

Comment: it is stuck on Launching xxx then attaching to xxxx
it is on xcode9

Comment: what error you are getting when trying to run. or u are not even able to select simulator?

Comment: @DrailanJohnTerrible what you did to solve this  ?

Comment: @Sujit ive reinstalled xcode from the app store sadly.